# how to count the hours in spec time ranges

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

Here is the sample data:

| id | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-12-29 09:00:00 | 2023-12-31 06:00:00 |
| 2 | 2023-12-28 09:00:00 | 2023-12-31 13:00:00 |

I plan to get the times of each hour in this spec times.
For example, let the sample above as input, then the output is like:

| id | hour | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 1 | 6 | 2 |
| 1 | 7 | 1 |
| 1 | 8 | 1 |
| 1 | 9 | 1 |
| 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 1 | 11 | 1 |
| 1 | 12 | 1 |
| 1 | 13 | 1 |
| 1 | 14 | 1 |
| 1 | 15 | 1 |
| 1 | 16 | 1 |
| 1 | 17 | 1 |
| 1 | 18 | 1 |
| 1 | 19 | 1 |
| 1 | 20 | 1 |
| 1 | 21 | 1 |
| 1 | 22 | 1 |
| 1 | 23 | 1 |

Right now I use """explode function""" in sparksql, but due to the limitation in clusters, the calculation takes time much longer than I thought.
Thus how to get the result without using 'explode' in sparksql?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using the explode function by counting the number of full days between the start and end datetimes, and then adjusting the count using the conditions:

- add 1 to the count if the hour occurs on the first day after `start_time`
- add 1 to the count if the hour occurs on the last day before `end_time`

[image]

To get all of the hours, we can create an `hour` DataFrame that contains a single column of hours 0-23, and then cross join it to the original DataFrame.

```
hour = spark.createDataFrame([h for h in range(24)], IntegerType()).toDF("hour")

df.crossJoin(hour).withColumn(
    'full_days', F.datediff('end_time','start_time') - 1
).withColumn(
    'start_day_included', (F.col('hour') >= F.hour('start_time')).cast(IntegerType())
).withColumn(
    'end_day_included', (F.col('hour') <= F.hour('end_time')).cast(IntegerType())
).withColumn(
    'cnt', F.col('full_days') + F.col('start_day_included') + F.col('end_day_included')
).select(
    'id','hour','cnt'
)

+---+----+---+
| id|hour|cnt|
+---+----+---+
|  1|   0|  2|
|  1|   1|  2|
|  1|   2|  2|
|  1|   3|  2|
|  1|   4|  2|
|  1|   5|  2|
|  1|   6|  2|
|  1|   7|  1|
|  1|   8|  1|
|  1|   9|  2|
|  1|  10|  2|
|  1|  11|  2|
|  1|  12|  2|
|  1|  13|  2|
|  1|  14|  2|
|  1|  15|  2|
|  1|  16|  2|
|  1|  17|  2|
|  1|  18|  2|
|  1|  19|  2|
|  1|  20|  2|
|  1|  21|  2|
|  1|  22|  2|
|  1|  23|  2|
|  2|   0|  3|
|  2|   1|  3|
|  2|   2|  3|
|  2|   3|  3|
|  2|   4|  3|
|  2|   5|  3|
|  2|   6|  3|
|  2|   7|  3|
|  2|   8|  3|
|  2|   9|  4|
|  2|  10|  4|
|  2|  11|  4|
|  2|  12|  4|
|  2|  13|  4|
|  2|  14|  3|
|  2|  15|  3|
|  2|  16|  3|
|  2|  17|  3|
|  2|  18|  3|
|  2|  19|  3|
|  2|  20|  3|
|  2|  21|  3|
|  2|  22|  3|
|  2|  23|  3|
+---+----+---+
```